# Ocaml Convertion type to string

Tags: ocaml

I have a question can I convert type unit() to string i mean I have a function that does a process after that the type of the output is unit() and I need to convert it to a string can I do that

Comment: What would that string be, do you think? You could very easily write a function that takes a `unit` and returns a `string`, but `unit` has only one value, so it would be a really boring function.

Comment: This is a perfect example of an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). You're too focused on the details, to the point that the question doesn't make any sense. What's the bigger picture of what you're trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 2):

This is a very literal answer to your question. A function with type `unit -> string` which is total, pure, and produces a unique `string` value for every possible value of type `unit`:

```
let unit_to_string () = "unit"
```

I don't think it will solve your actual problem, but perhaps it will somehow lead you to better identify and describe your problem.